# Exception handler - Printing a message And a variable in a single println Line

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a little problem that I need help with.

For this assignment (Lesson 12 HW9) name NumberFormatException,I had to do the following below

"Calculator.java, is a simple command-line calculator. Note that the program terminates if any operand is nonnumeric. Write a program with an exception handler that deals with nonnumeric operands. Your program should display a message that informs the user of the wrong operand before exiting (see the figure shown below)."

```
c:\exercise>java Exercise12_01 "4 + 5"

4 + 5 = 9

c:\exercise>java Exercise12_01 "4 - 5"

4 - 5 = -1

c:\exercise>java Exercise12_01 "4x - 5"
```

Wrong Input: 4x
SO all the math parts of the coding is finished, correct, and works, the only part I cant seem to figure out is: " display a message that informs the user of the wrong operand before exiting" Wrong Input: 4x. I need to know what I can do to show not only the error message, but the error input as well. the part where it show the error message to the user is at the end of the code at

Also another point i forgot to mention. the problem is that the User Might get only "N" or "V" wrong, and i dont know how to put only the Variable that is wrong while leaving the other variable alone
EX: if user put 4x - 5 (which is N - V), i just want to post 4x(N) and not 5(V) so i can show the user what the input was wrong

```
catch(InputMismatchException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Bad input, please correct your operard."); 
} //need to add the input error as well
```

here the full code, thank you

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberFormatException {

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
        Scanner Read = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
//          System.out.println("What is your number?");
            System.out.println("please enter an equation");
            int n=Read.nextInt();
            char operands;
            operands=Read.next().charAt(0); //reading up till the next space and pulling the first character it read
//          System.out.println("What is your operand?");
//          operands=Read.next().charAt(0);
//      
//              
//          System.out.println("What is a second number?");
            int v=Read.nextInt();
//          System.out.println("The second number you entered was "+v);
            if (operands == '+')
                System.out.println(n+"+"+v+"="+addition(n, v));
            if (operands == '-')
                System.out.println(n+"-"+v+"="+subtraction(n, v));
            if (operands == '*')
                System.out.println(n+"*"+v+"="+multiply(n, v));
            if (operands == '/')
                System.out.println(n+"/"+v+"="+division(n, v));

        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Bad input, please correct your operard."); //
        }
    }


        public static int addition(int n, int v){
        return n+v;
    }
    public static int subtraction(int n, int v){
        return n-v;
    }
    public static int multiply(int n, int v){
        return n * v;
    }
    public static int division(int n, int v){
        return n/v;
    }

}
```

You can copy and post into eclipse if you want to >.< thanks

---

PS: if you think your having deja vu with this title and question, your not, I accidentally posted the wrong code at the bottom with the previous post, sorry about that guys but here the right code

PS2: ok the user at the bottom with his version of the code answer the question, but there another issue.

there one issue im doing, is there a way to show the input as well. Im trying to show 4x as the error as well with the printout you modify but it doesnt come out

System.out.println("Bad input, please correct your first operand." + n);

I tried that just now but it want me to declare n =0 So when i did, but then : "Bad input, please correct your first operand.0" it put a zero instead of the 4x how can i fix this, a string conversion? please and thank you

Comment: You need just 2 try/catch blocks, one around n = Read.nextInt() and one around v = Read.nextInt(), or get Strings, which you convert later.

Comment: You could have edited your previous question instead of registering again and made a new one but anyway ... Reading the problem definition, I think that you don't have to ask the user to enter data. You should use directly args[0] from the main method. You have to parse that String that is in the format FirstOperand[blank]Operator[blank]SecondOperand. If FirstOperand is not an int, error. If SecondOperand is not an int, error. If Operator is not defined, error. Else do the operation.

Comment: thanks for your advice and tip, sorry about re-posting it, im new to stockflow and took me a while to know you can only post 1 question a day or do edit. I couldnt delete it since it was answer fast, but now i know

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of parsing the input and checking validity. But using your code as base this is what you can do to make it work. Add an additional try/catch clause for each integer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    int v;
    System.out.println("Please enter an equation");
    try {
        n = Read.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Bad input, please correct your first operand.");
        return;
    }
    char operands;
    operands = Read.next().charAt(0); //reading up till the next space and pulling the first character it read
    try {
        v = Read.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Bad input, please correct your second operand.");
        return;
    }
    if (operands == '+')
        System.out.println(n + "+" + v + "=" + addition(n, v));
    if (operands == '-')
        System.out.println(n + "-" + v + "=" + subtraction(n, v));
    if (operands == '*')
        System.out.println(n + "*" + v + "=" + multiply(n, v));
    if (operands == '/')
        System.out.println(n + "/" + v + "=" + division(n, v));

}


public static int addition(int n, int v) {
    return n + v;
}

public static int subtraction(int n, int v) {
    return n - v;
}

public static int multiply(int n, int v) {
    return n * v;
}

public static int division(int n, int v) {
    return n / v;
}
```

}

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much, wow such a simple way to fix this, thanks

but there one issue im doing, is there a way to show the input as well 
Im trying to show 4x as the error as well with the printout you modify but it doesnt come out 

System.out.println("Bad input, please correct your first operand." + n);

I tried that just now but it want me to declare n =0 
So when i did, but then : 
"Bad input, please correct your first operand.0" 
it put a zero instead of the 4x
how can i fix this, a string conversion? please and thank you,

Comment: Well, since the reason an Exception is thrown is that Read.nextInt() fails the operand with erroneous format is never actually read thus it will still be 0. What you could do is in the catch clause, read the failing input as a string and print that instead.

Comment: `System.out.println("Bad input, correct " + Read.next() + " and try again.")`

Should work. Please mark as resolved if this helps.